# c how this codes control statement working

Tags: c++, if-statement

i tried this program but it does not give any output

```
  int i=1,j=2,k=3;
    if(i>j)
       if(i>k)    (this will not get executed)
        cout<<"hello";   (but this should get executed right)
     else
        cout<<"hai";
```

which if belongs to which else

Comment: This is neither Java nor C.

Comment: The `cout<<"hello";` is in the path that does not get executed.

Comment: The else is bound to the inner most if.  If you want it bound to the outer-most, use curly braces around the outside of the inner if/cout

Comment: This is why you use brackets.

Comment: `-Wmisleading-indentation` - enable that warning *now* and get in to the habit of using braces.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve], as it is shown is neither compilable nor complete

Comment: Brackets are recommended even if you just have one statement to execute in either if or else part. Use brackets and make your life easier.

Comment: This post sounds like a homework.. if you had _tried_ to explore other C/C++ tutorials/book/references, then at least share the links of your references/study if all your online search failed. Rule book : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Happy Learning,, ( :

Comment: Try reading some more information about if conditions and how they work with and without using curly braces `{}`

Answer (score 4):

The code you've written is equivalent to this...

```
int i=1,j=2,k=3;
if(i>j) // false
{
    if(i>k) // not evaluated, but would also be false
    {
        cout<<"hello";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"hai";
    }
}
```

Because you didn't include the braces to make it clear what you wanted, the compiler had to decide what to do, and in this circumstance it always attaches the 'else' to the nearest 'if' that won't produce nonsense. When you do add the braces, it is very easy for you -- and the compiler -- to know which 'if' the 'else' belongs to.

This is probably what you wanted:

```
int i=1,j=2,k=3;
if(i>j) // false
{
    if(i>k) // not evaluated, but would also be false
    {
        cout<<"hello";
    }
}
else
{
    cout<<"hai"; // this is now executed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> 1. if(i>j)
> 2.    if(i>k)    (this will not get executed)
> 3.        cout<<"hello";   (but this should get executed right)
> ```

The expression 3. is a sub-expression of 2. If the expression 2. is not executed, then none of its sub-expressions will be executed either, so your assumption must be incorrect.

> which if belongs to which else

There is only one `else`. `else` belongs to the nearest predecessor `if`. Since 2. is nearer, it belongs to that. Example:

```
if (x)    // 1
    if(y) // 2
        ;
    else  // belongs to 2, because it's nearer
        ;
else      // belongs to 1
    ;

if (x) {   // 1
    if(y)  // 2
        ;
} else     // belongs to 1, because 2 is not a direct predecessor
```